# ip address of a computer that has no screen

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have 2 computers with debian installed on both. One computer has no sceen or othe prepherels accept ethernet port. I've connected them through a lan cable and shared the intenet to be used by the computer that has no sceen. However, I'd like to ssh this computet but I don't know its ip address. BtW, I dont have a router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/w/Home). It will give you the list of devices in the network.